# C++ (среда Qtcreator) error: allocation of incomplete type 'Ui::Tasks' note: forward declaration of 'Ui::Tasks'

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator

Когда в проекте был один файл task_box.ui, то всё работало хорошо. При добавлении второго файла формы tasks.ui, аналогичным образом, во втором (tasks.cpp) вылезли ошибки... Никак не могу их побороть...

tasks.cpp
[image: tasks.cpp]

tasks.h
[image: tasks.h]

.pro
[image: .pro]

tasks.ui
[image: tasks.ui]

Почему на первом файле аналогичный код работает без ошибок, а на втором ругается?

Comment: Сборку проекта запустите. Скорее всего автогенерируемые `ui_` файлы не создались, вот clang code model их и не видит

Comment: Файлы пересоздавались уже. Удалены исходные, запущена сборка, появились новыефайлы ui_tasks.h и ui_task_box.h. К сожалению, это не помогло(((

Comment: что значит "не помогло"? сборка завершилась удачно? или были ошибки сборки? если были, то какие?

Comment: ui_***.h собрались заново, а ошибки, выделенные красным и желтым появились в разделе "Проблемы"

Comment: Покажите файл tasks.ui в текстовом виде (не в дизайнере). Его можно увидеть, открыв его в дизайнере и нажав escape

Comment: Скрин tasks.ui добавлен после перенесения из /src в Формы

Answer (score 1):

Такую ошибку можно ещё исправить, создавая новый ui-файл не отдельно, а целый класс, который включает в себя как *.ui, так и *.h, *.cpp: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем скопировать содержимое со старых файлов(в которых ошибка возникла) на новосозданные. Если в файлах исходного кода есть отсылки и реализации на слоты, воссоздайте их по названию слотов в дизайнерском(*.ui) файле. Исходники могут ругаться на места "ui->..." , мол реализации нет:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
, но компиляция(пусть и с ошибками) должна решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась при переносе файлов tasks.h tasks.cpp tasks.ui из папки src в корневой каталог, т.е. в "формы", "исходники" и "заголовочные". Qt перестал ругаться. Не знаю почему так?? Возможно из-за того, что изначально форма tasks.ui была MainWindow.ui и находилась в основном каталоге "формы"...